# Formatting datagridview cells background doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, visual-c#-express-2010

I have some code that should change the background of a datagridview cell when the value in that named cell is lower than 5.

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {

        if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("stock"))
        {

            int intValue = (int)e.Value;

            if (intValue <= 5)
            {
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                e.CellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.DarkRed;
                e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
                if (!e.CellStyle.Font.Bold)
                {
                    e.CellStyle.Font = new Font(e.CellStyle.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
                }
                e.CellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;

            }
            
        }
}
```

The error I get is:

> When you try to cast a number, be sure that its value is minor than infinite.
>
> Make sure that the origin type is convertible in the destination type

I just want to check whether an integer in the datagridview cell is greater or lower than 5.
If yes, add a red background to the cell.

What is wrong with that code? I managed to make it work as you see it in the datagridview, but when I try to print the content with DGVPrinter class from codeproject.com, it fails with the above mentioned error.

Any clue?

The error I get calling the DGVPrinter class is located on this line:

```
int intValue = (int)e.Value;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the value of e.Value when you get this error?

Comment: try with int intValue = int.Parse(e.Value.ToString());

Comment: Thanks Josef. Unfortunately it doesn't work even with your mod.

Comment: @Bayeni the value of e.Value is exactly what I expect it to be. I "see" numbers, integer ones. I display it in a Messagebox.Show and the value I get is 3 or 5 and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot clearly shows that the value of `e.Value` is "pezzi", which is not a number.

If there is a possibility that some of the values will be numbers, and some will be non-numbers (or blank), you should use `TryParse()`:

```
int intValue;

if (int.TryParse(e.Value, out intValue) && intValue <= 5)
{
    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    e.CellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.DarkRed;
    e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
    if (!e.CellStyle.Font.Bold)
    {
        e.CellStyle.Font = new Font(e.CellStyle.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
    }
    e.CellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
}
```

Comment: I'll try your solution. Anyway, e.Value is not "pezzi". "Pezzi" is the name of the column that I check before checking the content, i.e. the e.Value. I'm going to try your hint. Let you know.

Comment: Ok, it doens't work. That's why TryParse works with (string, out int) and the e.Value is not a string. The debugger states it is an object. So now I am a bit confused.

Comment: @Aptivus In your screenshot, I can clearly see a little window showing `e.Value - "pezzi"`. I suggest you pause the code in the debugger and inspect the values of the objects you have available to you. I think you are making incorrect assumptions about the values they have.